# QBWC1013: Error connecting to QuickBooks. 0x80040408 - Full path to company file is included

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbwc

I am having issues with the QuickBooks Web Connector connecting to my company file when QB is closed. Here is the log:

```
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'Test Company IMPORT - TEST2' has STARTED
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: Test Company IMPORT - TEST2
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): Test Company IMPORT - TEST2
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
20130711.18:09:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20130711.18:09:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v2.0 at /fp/qb/v1.0/import.php">
20130711.18:09:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.30">
20130711.18:09:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20130711.18:09:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20130711.18:09:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'Test Company IMPORT - TEST2', username = 'omc_main'
20130711.18:09:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="omc_main"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20130711.18:09:38 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Received from authenticate() following parameters:<authRet[0]="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"><authRet[1]="C:\fp\xxxxxx.FPCOPY.qbw"><authRet[2]=""><authRet[3]="">
20130711.18:09:38 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceName() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceName has been set to Test Company IMPORT - TEST2
20130711.18:09:38 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceSessionTicket() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceSessionTicket has been set to ad5b2bc2-7101-6344-4d10-d95b2065c36b
20130711.18:09:38 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : User authenticated.
20130711.18:09:38 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.
20130711.18:09:38 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20130711.18:09:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.handleAllOtherError() : QBWC1013: Error connecting to QuickBooks. Returning error message to application.
Could not start QuickBooks.
20130711.18:09:40 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : *** Calling connectionError() with following parameters:<wcTicket="ad5b2bc2-7101-6344-4d10-d95b2065c36b"><hresult="0x80040408"><message="Could not start QuickBooks.">
20130711.18:09:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : Received from connectionError() following parameters:<tryAgain="done">
20130711.18:09:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Application sent back DONE. Job ending.
20130711.18:09:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20130711.18:09:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20130711.18:09:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

As you can see the full path to the file is properly included (and I've triple checked the path is correct):

```
<authRet[1]="C:\fp\xxxxxx.FPCOPY.qbw">
```

Any one have any ideas??

Comment: What does the QBSDKlog.txt file say? Might have to enable verbose logging.

Comment: Is C:\fp\xxxxxx.FPCOPY.qbw the path that QuickBooks reports when you hit F2 on your keyboard while in QuickBooks?